# Pokémon energy cards with circled numbers

Tags: pokemon

I have these Grass type energy cards in my collection, they're from 2017, fairly new. But I have no idea why they're numbered. I can't even remember where I got them from. The numbers are on each card in a white and blue circle, not quite at the bottom, right corner.

[image]

Comment: I guess what I mean to ask is, what are the numbers for? What do they mean?

Comment: I have a wild suspicion that they may come from some kind of demonstration deck - the numbers help put the deck into a fixed order so that the demo always goes the same way.

Comment: Trainer kit cards are numbered.

Answer (score 6):

These are from [Sun & Moon Trainer Kit: Alolan Sandslash & Alolan Ninetales](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sun_%26_Moon_Trainer_Kit:_Alolan_Sandslash_%26_Alolan_Ninetales_(TCG)), the first instance of [Trainer Kit](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Deck#Trainer_Kit) that uses those circled numbers instead of the previous approach of using set number for purpose of sorting the two half decks for a demonstration game.